# ReactJS Visual Studio Import Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-2015, npm, react-router

I have created an MVC 4.5 project and Installed ReactJS from Nuget . Um in the verge of creating an SPA application using react js

Inorder to use react-router I have installed npm and added package.json as follows

```
                {
                    "dependencies": {
                        "react": "^0.14.7",
                        "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
                        "react-router": "^2.0.0"
                    },
                    "devDependencies": {
                        "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
                        "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
                        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
                        "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
                        "http-server": "^0.8.5",
                        "webpack": "^1.12.13",
                        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
                    },
                    "name": "ASP.NET",
                    "private": true,
                    "version": "1.0.0"
                }
```

I have index.js file which has  following lines of codes

```
                import React from 'react'
                import {render} from 'react-dom'
                import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
```

Um getting following errors after running the application

> reactindex:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

this is my project setup

[image]

How may I fix this issue ?

Comment: You need an ES6 transpiler like babel or typescript. `import` is an ES6 keyword.

Comment: insalled babel "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
                        "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
                        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
                        "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0", still getting error @jzm

Comment: Ok. You need either webpack (preferrable, but more complicated) or gulp to "compile" your JS into ES5 syntax. Because if you're just linking to your index.js, your browser won't be able to understand ES6 code.

Comment: Thank you , I ll work on it @jzm

Comment: Solution worked thought it has introduced a new error require is not identified , used babel and plugins but still getting the error